# ServiceStack.Text's CSVSerializer can't read umlauts

Tags: c#, csv, utf-8, servicestack-text

I have CSV files with German language values.  So umlaut symbols etc like: **Fläcke**.
These can be seen in notepad and here on stackoverflow!

I'm using ServiceStack.Text's DeserializeFromString() method in their CSVSerializer to read my CSV file but the language specific symbols are not read correctly.

Instead, they are all replaced with a single non language symbol (�)

I have tried setting the following with no success:

```
CsvSerializer.UseEncoding = PclExport.Instance.GetUTF8Encoding(true);
```

I will also need to write out these CSV files again maintaining the German language symbols.

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

I already read the file using:

```
File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Changing this to read the default encoding got it to work:

```
File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default);
```

ServiceStack you're OK;-)